# C++ multi-inheritance, error in delete object

Tags: c++, inheritance

I created this simple C++ program:

```
#include <iostream>

class Base1 {
public:
    virtual void method1() = 0;
};

class Base2 {
public:
    virtual void method2() = 0;
};

class B : public Base1, public Base2 {
public:
    void method1() override {
        std::cout << "method1 from B\n";
    }
    void method2() override {
        std::cout << "method2 from B\n";
    }
};

int main() {
    Base1 *x = new B;
    x->method1();
    delete x;
    return 0;
}
```

And it works fine. But if I change the code in main function to:

```
int main() {
    Base2 *x = new B;
    x->method2();
    delete x;
    return 0;
}
```

When I run this code, I have this runtime error:
`free(): invalid pointer`

Why this error when I use base2 class and it works fine with base1? How can I fix it?

Comment: For polymorphic classes you always need virtual destructors. Doesn't your compiler emit warnings about that when you build? Then please enable more warnings, and treat them as errors that must be fixed. See e.g. [here to see the warning](https://godbolt.org/z/cG44fYoGT).

Comment: You have undefined behaviour in both cases.   Both the base classes need to have a `virtual` destructor to avoid that.     Undefined behaviour may produce a runtime error but, equally, it can seem to run correctly.   Such is the nature of the word "undefined" -  any outcome is possible.

Answer (score 4):

You need your base classes destructors to be virtual if you are aiming to use those polymorphically.

```
class base1 {
public:
    virtual ~base1() = default;
    virtual void method1() = 0;
};

class base2 {
public:
    virtual ~base2() = default;
    virtual void method2() = 0;
};

class B : public base1, public base2 {
public:
    void method1() override {
        std::cout << "method1 from B\n";
    }
    void method2() override {
        std::cout << "method2 from B\n";
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks Someprogrammerdude, Peter and Eduard. Yes, with virtual destructor the problem is fixed. 

The thing that stopped me was because the problem was present in one case and not in the other. But now the problem is solved :)